# How to add third party package external/openssh in android 10 build system

Tags: android-source, openssh, android-10.0

I want to add openssh as a part of system.img in android 10.

I have tried
./build/make/target/product/cfi-common.mk:24:    external/openssh \
./build/make/target/product/base_system.mk:268:    external/openssh \

I was able to do that with #mmm external/openssh

But not getting same think after making changes in .mk files.

Kindly help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's not clear to me what you want to do. Where did you get openssh from? Did it already contain an Android-specific build file (Android.mk/Android.bp) or did you write one yourself? In general, you would need to add the module defined in such a build file to the PRODUCT_PACKAGES build variable (e.g. in the device/ or vendor/ subfolder that is your customization point).

Comment: Also, you would likely need further modifications to make openssh functional, e.g. adapt the SE Linux policies (and maybe also the iptables rules?).

Comment: yes is is having Android.mk.

Comment: So basically you using this? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/openssh/+/refs/heads/master/Android.mk The relevant part is the `LOCAL_MODULE := ssh` part. This is the name that you have to add to the PRODUCT_PACKAGES variable. It's also the name you can use for manual building, e.g. `make ssh`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `PRODUCT_PACKAGES += ssh` to your device.mk